Flutter Error: Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(channel-error, Unable to establish connection on channel.)
I'm working on a Flutter project. Here is my main.dart file.
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
  runApp(MyApp());
}

While running it, here is the error I obtained :

ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception:
PlatformException(channel-error, Unable to establish connection on
channel., null, null)

What can I try to fix this?

can you share more code?

This is the part causing the issue in my code.

I noticed you've made some edits to your question after I made some changes for clarity. Just a heads-up, the edits I made were aimed at improving understanding and assisting you more effectively.

Yes, the modifications you suggested have been applied to my question to improve its clarity and understanding, as well as to assist me more effectively.

Did you manage to solve the issue? I am getting the same error

I didn't get the solution

Try this option instead of DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform:
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: const FirebaseOptions(
      apiKey: "project apikey",
      appId: "project appId",
      messagingSenderId: "project messagingSenderId",
      projectId: "projectId",
    ),
  );
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

You can find your apiKey, appId, messagingSenderId and ProjectId from firebase's setting Project settings/General.

Yes, I've tried that as well, but I still get the same error. I can't seem to understand.
